# parsing nested semi structured json data with pandas and json_normalize with null value

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to flatten a semi-structured json dataset having the following structure, and containing null values for some key/values.

A sample of this dataset is the following:

```json
{"metrics":{"key1":xx, "key2":xy}, "audiences":["element1", "element2"], "sets":{audience_list:["element3", "element4"]}, "visit_id":"1"}
{"metrics":{"key1":xxx, "key3":xxy}, "audiences":["element11", "element22"], "sets":{audience_list:["element33", "element44"]}, "visit_id":"2"}
{"metrics":{"key1":value1, "key2":value2}, "audiences":["element1", "element2"], "visit_id":"3"}
```

I have tried to normalize it using panda, but I am not sure I am doing it correctly. I am able to parse the first element, but if I add the other elements, I have an error.

This is what I have tried using json_normalize:

```
data = pd.read_json(body, lines=True, orient='records')
            df = pd.json_normalize(data['metrics'])
```

The expected output would be each key as a column, i.e: metrics, audiences, sets, visit_id

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's not a JSON. It could be `[{"metrics"..."visit_id":"1"},{"metrics"..."visit_id":"2"},{"metrics"..."visit_id":"3"}]`, and then it would be a JSON.

Comment: yes indeed, I totally agree with you. So having backslashes at the end of each line doesn't give him the JSON format ? In this case, which approach do you recommend  for this use case please ?

Comment: `"something":...` is already not JSON, it would be `{"something":...}`. Free-floating backslashes are not part of JSON specs either, but linebreaks outside strings are allowed. See what JSON is on https://www.json.org/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: yes indeed, my bad I wanted to create a sample of my data and forgot the most important. May be we could consider each row as a single json record ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended converting it to a csv file:

```py
with io.BytesIO() as csv_buffer:
     json_str.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False, compression='gzip')
```

and then, restructure it in the destination database